# Clean URL's with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have downloaded the phpDolphon Social Networking Script. It is great, however, it does not have clean URLs. Does anybody know how to do it?

Here is an example of the index page:

`mydomain.com/index.php?a=feed`

and I want to change it to:

`mydomain.com/`

---

Here is an example of the profile page:

`mydomain.com/index.php?a=profile&u=daniel`

and I want to change it to:

`mydomain.com/user/daniel`

---

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-+_%*?]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-+_%*?]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&u=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?a=feed
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?a=profile&u=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /user/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)$ /index.php?a=profile&u=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?a=feed [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What's with all the `${THE_REQUEST}` and ``\`` and `[L]` and `[QSA]`?

Comment: @Rudie it's if there's URLs outside of his control that still point to the old `index.php?something` URLs. The `L` ends rewriting inthe current iteration, and `QSA` adds the query string if it exists.

Comment: What if old urls still point to those? They won't stop working... The app itself creates only those urls.

Comment: @Rudie they won't stop working but this redirects it so the browser shows the "Clean" URL

Comment: Oooooh. Clever. If it's an internal redirect. If it's an actual HTTP redirect, there will be a lot of those, since the app itself doesn't make pretty urls. Thanks

Comment: @Rudie Unlike URI's that are sent through the `RewriteRule`'s pattern, the patterin the `%{THE_REQEUST}` is *not canonicalized*, which means if someone malforms the link to, say, `http://domain.com//index.php`, the `/+` will match that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need very specific rules:

```
# no 'feeds' in alias
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?a=feed (maybe it needs a /)

# 'user' in one, 'profile' in other
RewriteRule ^user/(\w\d+)$ index.php?a=profile&u=$1

etc
```